# Many-to-many relationship with 'through' model returning error on migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to implement a system which allows for two `Profile` model objects to be a part of a `Pair` model object.

Here is the Profile, followed by a Pair model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    pair = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Pair',
                                   symmetrical=False,
                                   related_name='pair_to+')

class Pair(models.Model):
    requester = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='pairing_requester')
    accepter = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='pairing_accepter')
    requester_learns = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    requester_teaches = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
```

The relationship between profiles should be symmetrical, such that (profile1, profile2) are a unique object and I should not expect a (profile2, profile1) to be created.

So, per [this article,](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/) I am trying to create the relationship.

Upon `makemigrations`, I am receiving the error:

```
ERRORS:
<function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x1044b47b8>: (models.E022) <function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x1044b47b8> contains a lazy reference to user_profile.pair, but app 'user_profile' doesn't provide model 'pair'.
user_profile.Profile.pair: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'Pair', which has not been installed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Pair(models.Model):
    requester = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='pairing_requester')
    accepter = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='pairing_accepter')
    requester_learns = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    requester_teaches = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)  

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    pair = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Pair',
                                   symmetrical=False,
                                   related_name='pair_to+')
```

the thing that you are doing wrong is you need to mention the model before calling a relation to another model, django will create PAIR model first then will install model to the other model. so use this and before making migration drop the old migration files

Comment: Then is there no way to keep them in different models.py files?

Comment: you can keep it, but you need to create the table first before assinging it, or else django wont understand to which table it will create relation too, as the table doesnt exist when you are creating the relation

Comment: I've tried dropping the migrations and migrating the Pair model first alone but receive the same error. Could it relate to specifying Pair model as a string in Profile model?

Comment: the problem is with the database, i guess you need to drop your database and then drop the migration files then try to migrate from first, hope that will solve your error

Comment: Recreating db causes the same error.  edit: one thing that does cause change: when I `import Pair` into the Profile model file, it causes a `cannot import name 'Profile'` error instead.

Comment: tell me the steps that you have tried? 1st drop the whole database, create a new database with the same name, 2nd delete all the migrations files from all the apps migration folder except the __init__.py file. 3rd run migrate, makemigrations, migrate

Comment: I have done exactly that. Dropped the database, create new, delete all migrations including other apps. Migrate and makemigrations both return the very same error. These are on two separate models.py files. On the profile.py, I am not importing the `Pair model`--simply writing `"Pair"` as string. On the pairs.py file, I am importing `Profile`.

Comment: i am sorry, did you created 2 model files in the same app?? that is not going to work bro, keep the models in the same models.py file, as an app can contain only one models.py file

Comment: They are in separate apps. But theyve worked now that I placed them in the same app and placed the Pair after Profile. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: glad could help bro :) @simonsays